Software to change Windows appearence (from folder icons to UI)
I’m looking for a software or a set of tools that can help me customize the overall appearance of my Windows system. Specifically, I want to modify various visual elements, such as:

Folder icons
User Interface (taskbar, Start menu, etc)
System fonts and colors

Requirements:

Compatibility: Works with Windows 10 and/or Windows 11.
User-friendly: Preferably with an intuitive interface.
Performance: Minimal impact on system performance.
Budget: Open to free or paid tools, but I’d prefer the open-source free ones or reasonably priced options.


Winaero Tweaker is a very popular tool for precisely this -- and it should meet all of the requirements you've laid out.

See also: https://alternativeto.net/software/winaero-tweaker/

While true, your answer could be improved by providing more information on those products.
